# Rebuilding PrimeFaces jar file (missing PushServlet)

Tags: maven, primefaces, jar, atmosphere, rebuild

I have downloaded the source code from [primefaces github](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces), extracted the zip and opened its `pom.xml` in `Intellij` 
modified a class and in Lifecycle > package chose `Run'primefaces[package]'` as it apparently creates a  `primefaces-6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar` in target folder.
the log says Build process is successful but when I add the jar file as library, my project's artifact won't deploy with this exception:

```
[2018-10-10 12:51:29,281] Artifact SERP2ANT: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2018-10-10 12:51:29,282] Artifact SERP2ANT: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SERP2.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.push.PushServlet from [Module \"deployment.SERP2ANT.war\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.push.PushServlet from [Module \"deployment.SERP2ANT.war\" from Service Module Loader]"},"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {"Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SERP2"],"Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.clustering.web.route.default-server","jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa","jboss.txn.service.remote","jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SERP2","jboss.xts.handlers","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.default-service-provider-registry.ejb","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.default-service-provider-registry.web","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.ejb.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.entity","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.local-query","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.timestamps","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.server.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.server.default","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.default-server","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.ejb.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.server.default","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.web.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.ejb.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.entity","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.local-query","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.timestamps","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.server.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.server.default","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.web.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.web.default-server","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.web.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.ejb.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.entity","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.local-query","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.timestamps","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.server.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.server.default","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.web.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.web.default-server","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.web.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.ejb.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.ejb.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.entity","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.local-query","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.timestamps","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.server.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.server.default","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.default-server","org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.ejb","org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.hibernate","org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.local","org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.server","org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.web","org.wildfly.clustering.default-command-dispatcher-factory","org.wildfly.clustering.group.hibernate","org.wildfly.clustering.group.server","org.wildfly.clustering.group.web","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.ejb.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.entity","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.local-query","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.timestamps","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.server.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.server.default","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.hibernate.local-query","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.hibernate.timestamps","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.server.default","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.web.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web.default-server","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.expiration","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.locking","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.memory","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.transaction","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.expiration","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.locking","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.memory","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.transaction","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.expiration","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.locking","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.memory","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.transaction","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.client-mappings","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.default-server","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.expiration","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.locking","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.memory","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.transaction","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.write","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.server","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.web","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.server","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.server.transport","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.web","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.web.transport","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache.ejb","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache.web","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache-configuration.server","org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache-configuration.web"]}}
```

is there a long list of dependencies I've to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original answer was deleted by a moderator.  I don't like there reason when my answer was correct and the accepted answer.  For those of you wondering the answer was because Primefaces has removed Push in version 6.3 which is why the OP was getting this error.  Once he removed it from the web.xml it worked again.

Comment: well it was a quick and correct answer, maybe they wanted me to wait for other answers as well, in any case just commenting that xml snippet of push servlet resolved my issue.